# Prop: Empty set is a subset of every set.

Tags: real-analysis

**Prop:** Empty set is a subset of every set.

**Pf:**. First consider the empty set. $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset \iff \emptyset \bigcap \emptyset = \emptyset $ and $\emptyset \bigcup \emptyset = \emptyset$.
$\emptyset \bigcap \emptyset =\{x\in \!\, \emptyset  \ \text{and} \ x\in \!\, \emptyset \!\,\}=\emptyset$ and $\emptyset \bigcup \emptyset =\{x\in \!\, \emptyset  \ \text{or} \ x\in \!\, \emptyset \!\,\}=\emptyset$. Thus, $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$.

Now consider a non-empty set $S$. $\emptyset \subseteq S \iff \emptyset \bigcap S = \emptyset $ and $\emptyset \bigcup S = S$. $\emptyset \bigcap S =  \{x \in S \ \text{and} \  x \in \emptyset \} = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \bigcup S =\{x\in \!\, S  \ \text{or} \ x\in \!\, \varnothing \!\,\}=S$.

Hence, $\emptyset \subseteq S$ as required $\square$. Does my proof look right?

Comment: This has been answered already elsewhere: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631042/direct-proof-of-empty-set-being-subset-of-every-set

Comment: Your proof looks fine.